# Can i use a function to change part of a object?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to/how would I change part of a object?

Like say if i wanted to change the move1 from "bite" to "Werewolf form"  and keep all of the other moves the same.

```
var Wolf = {move1:"Bite", move2:"Bark", move3:"Howl", move4:"Call Pack"}

document.getElementById('move1').innerHTML = Wolf.move1
```

Comment: I don't understand the question; `Wolf.move1 = "foo"` doesn't work?

Comment: You can change any part of any object.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects are mutables. You can do:

```
var Wolf = {move1:"Bite", move2:"Bark", move3:"Howl", move4:"Call Pack"}
Wolf.move1 = "Werewolf form";
document.getElementById('move1').innerHTML = Wolf.move1
```